# unable to run gmapping (couldn't find executable)

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running Ubuntu 18.04, ROS Melodic.
ROS root dir:  `/opt/ros/melodic/share`, catkin_ws dir= `/home/foo/catkin_ws`

I was trying to install gmapping because I'm going through [the navigation tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup#Mapping_.28map_server.29) and it says that I need to build a map for the upcoming tutorials and to do so, gmapping is required. I then cloned the [repo](https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping) in `/opt/ros/melodic/share` and run
`rosdep install gmapping`, sourced the environment **and** run `catkin_make`.

When I try to run it, as they say, via `rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=base_scan` it doesn't work, just outputs

`Couldn't find executable named slam_gmapping below /opt/ros/melodic/share/slam_gmapping/gmapping`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335304/unable-to-run-gmapping-(couldn%27t-find-executable)/) by [davidem](https://answers.ros.org/users/47142/davidem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2019-10-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-13**:
You have a from-source build of Melodic on Ubuntu `16.04`?

Why do you clone repositories into `/opt/ros/melodic/share`? Even if you are building packages from source, that is not where packages should be cloned to. It's very likely that the package hasn't been built.

Please clarify what sort of setup you really are running. gmapping has been released into both Kinetic and Melodic, so unless you absolutely must build Melodic from source on Xenial, using `apt` and a supported version of ROS would be very much preferred.

**Comment by [davidem](https://answers.ros.org/users/47142/davidem/) on 2019-10-14**:
Hi, thanks for your comment. I am cloning repos there because i don't want them to be included in my workspace, where i keep the packages i am working on. Or, at least, that's the meaning I give to the word "workspace", something where you work but not where your tools are, such as `catkin_ws`. i'm then running `rosdep install gmapping` and that call succeedes, or at least should.

Am i wrong to clone repos there? is there a way to do otherwise without cloning them into the ws, as that seems to be the problem?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-14**:
Please answer the question whether you are building ROS Melodic from source on Ubuntu Xenial.

And if yes, then why?

**Comment by [davidem](https://answers.ros.org/users/47142/davidem/) on 2019-10-14**:
I am sorry, I misstyped the version of Ubuntu, it's Beaver 18.04, anyway no, I downloaded it via apt but is it meaningful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I am sorry, I misstyped the version of Ubuntu, it's Beaver 18.04, anyway no, I downloaded it via apt but is it meaningful?

Yes.

Seeing as you aren't building ROS Melodic on Ubuntu Xenial and as you are on a supported architecture (as you've already installed ROS using `apt`) you can just install `gmapping` using `apt`:

```
sudo apt install ros-melodic-slam-gmapping
```

Is there any specific reason you did not do that?

Building ROS packages from source should not be your primary way of installing them. If possible, *always* prefer to install ROS packages using `apt` on Ubuntu.

I've explained how you can determine whether you can use `apt` (ie: whether binary packages are available) to install a package in #q320046.

In general there are very few circumstances in which building from source is needed or desirable. I would say for normal usage it's almost never needed. Except your own packages of course.

> I then cloned the repo in `/opt/ros/melodic/share`

If you must build packages from source, don't place them in that directory. It will not work.

Clone packages in the [source space](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/workspaces#Source_Space) of your workspace, run `rosdep` to install all dependencies and then build the workspace (using `catkin_make`, as you've been doing, or `catkin build` (from `catkin_tools`)). After `source`-ing the `devel/setup.bash` of your workspace, the package(s) should be available to you.

> and run `rosdep install gmapping`

while this is a valid command, I don't believe it does what you think it does in this case. It does not register the package with ROS, or something similar. `rosdep` is a tool used to install dependencies of ROS packages.

> sourced the environment and run `catkin_make`.

if you're building your workspace, those two steps should probably be reversed.

Refer to #q252478 for an example workflow that shows the steps in the correct order.

> Am i wrong to clone repos there? is there a way to do otherwise without cloning them into the ws, as that seems to be the problem?

Cloning repositories (ie: building packages from sources) does have its uses, but I would strongly suggest to only do it when absolutely needed. As I wrote in #q320046, there are quite a few steps to get right, multiple points at which things can fail, and it's always more time consuming than a simple `apt install`.

If you still want or need to build packages from sources, but don't want those packages in your 'main workspace', then I'd suggest to take a look at [workspace overlaying](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying). You place the packages you don't want in your main workspace in the underlay, build the underlay, `source` it and then continue working in your main workspace.

---

Finally: I would remove any packages you've placed in `/opt/ros/melodic/share` and try to install whatever you need using `apt`. If it's not available, use an underlay workspace.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2